# Point file with addresses, geocode Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I have a point file of stores in New York/New Jersey. The point file's attribute table has a field called addresses.

I also have a building footprint polygon file with the outlines of buildings.

Is there a way to assign each point to a polygon?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify what you mean by "assign each point to a polygon"?

Comment: you can likely make an arcgis geocoder/locator of 'single field' type using the polygons as the input dataset, then run the table of stores (i assume you mean table because if you had a point file you wouldn't need to geocode it...)... the geocoder will check each address in the stores table against the addresses in the polygon locator and create a georeferenced point at that location

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this by using an offset more than the distance the building is from the centerline.
Then after you have the address points perform (either) an intersect, or spatial join.
The difference will depend on the data you have and how accurate your centerline address ranges are. (also how up-to -date your building footprints are).
If you have addresses with no corresponding footprint the spatial join will put 2 points on a single building (making it difficult to determine which one is correct).
However if you have apt/mall addresses and their spread doesn't fall within a footprint you may want them all to attach to one building.
You will need to experiment with your data.